# Emacs daemon with configured packages on NixOS

Tags: emacs, daemon, nixos

The [NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#idm140737315573568) suggests configuring as below to launch Emacs as a daemon with some packages:

```
services.emacs.enable = true;
services.emacs.package = import /home/cassou/.emacs.d { pkgs = pkgs; };
```

However it is not clear what those `pkgs = pkgs` section mean. In my `configuration.nix` I already specified the list of Emacs packages I want:

```
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    # Emacs
    (emacsWithPackages (with emacsPackagesNg; [
      evil
      haskell-mode
      intero
      nix-mode
      org
      python-mode
    ]))
  }
```

My question: how do I make the daemon Emacs use these set of packages automatically? Currently they do not (only emacs launched directly does).

Answer (score 2):

**WORK IN PROGRESS ANSWER (see below)**

After reading up on the Nix language syntax I came with the solution of *moving* the package definitions under the `services.emacs.package` config:

```
  services.emacs.enable = true;
  services.emacs.package = with pkgs; (emacsWithPackages (with emacsPackagesNg; [
      evil
      haskell-mode
      intero
      nix-mode
      org
      python-mode
  ]));
```

Although this worked, whenever I add new packages to that list it does not (emacs does not load them). What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: When you add packages to the list and do `nixos-rebuild switch` does the emacs service restart?

Comment: Yes, I even tried restarting it manually. Nothing works.

Comment: Any news related to this? I'm having the same problem here, ..however even the suggested approach does not bring any emacs packages to the emacsclient in my case. In the standalone emacs executable, it works fine...

Answer (score -1):

Years later... (2021)

I just install a customised emacs definition:

`emacs.nix`

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

let
  myEmacs = pkgs.emacs;
  emacsWithPackages = (pkgs.emacsPackagesNgGen myEmacs).emacsWithPackages;
in
  emacsWithPackages (epkgs: (with epkgs.melpaStablePackages;
  [
    solarized-theme
  ]) ++ (with epkgs.melpaPackages; [
    alchemist
    all-the-icons
    auto-complete
    auto-compile
...
  ])
)
```

`configuration.nix`

```
  services.emacs.enable = true;
  services.emacs.package = pkgs.callPackage ./emacs.nix { };
```

Obviously the daemon is running when I switch, so I need to restart it for `emacs` to use the new configuration:

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild switch
$ systemctl --user restart emacs
```

Seems to me you didn't restart the daemon after switching.